# Revit Api Load Command - Auto Reload

Tags: revit-api

I'm working with the revit api, and one of its problems is that it locks the .dll once the command's run. You have to exit revit before the command can be rebuilt, very time consuming.

After some research, I came across this post on GitHub, that streams the command .dll into memory, thus hiding it from Revit. Letting you rebuild the VS project as much as you like.

The AutoReload Class impliments the revit IExteneralCommand Class which is the link into the Revit Program.

But the AutoReload class hides the actual source DLL from revit. So revit can't lock the DLL and lets one rebuilt the source file.

Only problem is I cant figure out how to implement it, and have revit execute the command. I guess my C# general knowledge is still too limited.

I created an entry in the RevitAddin.addin manifest that points to the AutoReload Method command, but nothing happens.

I've tried to follow all the comments in the posted code, but nothing seems to work; and no luck finding a contact for the developer.

Found at: https://gist.github.com/6084730.git

```
using System;

namespace Mine
{
    //  helper class
    public class PluginData
    {
        public DateTime _creation_time;
        public Autodesk.Revit.UI.IExternalCommand _instance;

    public PluginData(Autodesk.Revit.UI.IExternalCommand instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }
}

//
//   Base class for auto-reloading external commands that reside in other dll's
//   (that Revit never knows about, and therefore cannot lock)
//
public class AutoReload : Autodesk.Revit.UI.IExternalCommand
{
    // keep a static dictionary of loaded modules (so the data persists between calls to Execute)
    static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, PluginData> _dictionary;

    String _path;   // to the dll
    String _class_full_name;

    public AutoReload(String path, String class_full_name)
    {
        if (_dictionary == null)
        {
            _dictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, PluginData>();
        }
        if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(class_full_name))
        {
            PluginData data = new PluginData(null);
            _dictionary.Add(class_full_name, data);
        }
        _path = path;
        _class_full_name = class_full_name;
    }

    public Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result Execute(
        Autodesk.Revit.UI.ExternalCommandData commandData, 
        ref string message, 
        Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet elements)
    {
        PluginData data = _dictionary[_class_full_name];
        DateTime creation_time = new System.IO.FileInfo(_path).LastWriteTime;
        if (creation_time.CompareTo(data._creation_time) > 0)
        {
            //  dll file has been modified, or this is the first time we execute this command.
            data._creation_time = creation_time;
            byte[] assembly_bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_path);
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assembly_bytes);
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.IsClass && type.FullName == _class_full_name)
                {
                    data._instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Autodesk.Revit.UI.IExternalCommand;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // now actually call the command
        return data._instance.Execute(commandData, ref message, elements);
    }
}

//
//   Derive a class from AutoReload for every auto-reloadable command. Hardcode the path 
//   to the dll and the full name of the IExternalCommand class in the constructor of the base class.
//
[Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
[Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Regeneration(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.RegenerationOption.Manual)]
public class AutoReloadExample : AutoReload
{
    public AutoReloadExample()
        : base("C:\\revit2014plugins\\ExampleCommand.dll", "Mine.ExampleCommand")
    {
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not buy an SSD? Toying with `Assembly.Loadxxx` will just give you more problems than it would solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier approach: **Add-in Manager**

Go to [Revit Developer Center](http://www.autodesk.com/developrevit) and download the Revit SDK, unzip/install it, the check at **\Revit 2016 SDK\Add-In Manager** folder. With this tool you can load/reload DLLs without having to modify your code.

There is also some additional information at this [blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2014/05/revit-2015-add-in-manager.html).

Comment: The only thing you should be aware of with these kinds of approaches is that serialization may be problematic, if the same class is loaded in a few different times.

Comment: I looked at the add in manager; I thought it was quite a few steps just to run a command. But i guess if i'm just using it to develop a new command its not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can use the above code:

1. Create a new VS class project; name it anything (eg. AutoLoad)
2. Copy&Paste the above code in-between the namespace region
3. reference revitapi.dll & revitapiui.dll
4. Scroll down to AutoReloadExample class and replace the path to point
   your dll
5. Replace "Mine.ExampleCommand" with your plugins namespace.mainclass
6. Build the solution
7. Create an .addin manifest to point this new loader (eg.
   AutoLoad.dll)
8. your .addin should include "FullClassName" AutoLoad.AutoReloadExample

This method uses reflection to create an instance of your plugin and prevent Revit to lock your dll file! You can add more of your commands just by adding new classes like AutoReloadExample and point them with seperate .addin files.

Cheers